# how to get the below makefile condition working

Tags: makefile

```
FOLDER_NAME = $*

%.clean:
ifeq ($(FOLDER_NAME),cdr)
    @ echo " condition passed $(FOLDER_NAME)"
else
    @ echo " condition failed $(FOLDER_NAME)"
endif
```

While running make cdr.clean on this i get the below output.
condition failed cdr

Not able to figure out what could be the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. That is not a valid makefile. If you "run make on it" you will
simply see a syntax error. Please post a minimal but complete makefile that reproduces
your problem.

Comment: @Mike i have update with full makefile content

Answer (score 1):

The conditional `ifeq` is evaluated when the makefile is read. At that time `$*` evaluates to an empty string, so `ifeq` sees an empty `FOLDER_NAME`. The `$*` does only have meaning when the rule is evaluated at runtime later.

In order to achieve what you intend, you could either define different rules for your different cases (*clean2 below) or use a shell command to evaluate the condition (*clean3 below).

```
FOLDER_NAME = $*

cdr.clean2:
        @ echo " condition passed $(FOLDER_NAME)"

%.clean2:
        @ echo " condition failed $(FOLDER_NAME)"

%.clean3:
        @ if [ $(FOLDER_NAME) == cdr ]; \
            then echo " condition passed $(FOLDER_NAME)" ; \
            else echo " condition failed $(FOLDER_NAME)"; \
          fi
```